# Python script fails when launched from another location than its own folder

Tags: windows, permissions, python

I have a simple python script that I want to execute in the background periodically using the task scheduler in windows. The python script works fine if I execute it normally from a command line when in the same folder as it is, for example with the command "pythonw test.py". But if I move to a different folder and use the absolute path for the script instead, it fails. For example "pythonw C:/somefolder/test.py" when the command line is not currently in somefolder.

The script involves creating a file, so I know the script failed because no file is created. I am suspecting a permissions issue, but I've already tried to change the folder properties to give all users and even the permission group "Everyone" full control over the folder. What else can I try?

I have windows 10 pro, python 3

This is the python script although as I mentioned I know the code works fine normally:

```
import urllib.request, json, csv, time

with urllib.request.urlopen(***) as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    with open(time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") +".csv", 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        #csvwriter.writerow([datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%c")])
        csvwriter.writerow(data['chatters']['viewers'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I'm a dumbass. The script worked, it's just that the file wasn't created in the same folder as the script, but rather in the folder that it was launched from.